# WinUI 3 : Force Mouse Pointer to interact with a User Control, when it "souldn't"

Tags: c#, xaml, mouseevent, winui-3

I'm creating a WinUI 3 User Control that -for sake of simplicity- can be described as glorified slider:

- Whenever user presses their left click (`PointerPressed` event), Pointer movement starts being tracked.
- Whenever uses releases their left click (`PointerReleased` event), this tracking stops.

**Sample XAML**

```xml
<UserControl [...] >
    <Border Name="MainArea"
            PointerPressed="StartCapturing"
            PointerReleased="StopCapturing"
            PointerMoved="CaptureCoords"
            [...] >

        <!-- [...] -->

    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

**Sample C#**

```cs
bool _isCapturing = false;

private void CalculateCoords(PointerRoutedEventArgs args){

    // max distance is [w,h]. min distance is [0,0]
    var h = MainArea.ActualHeight;
    var w = MainArea.ActualWidth;
    
    // Coordinates relative to the MainArea element;
    var pos = args.GetCurrentPoint(MainArea).Position;
    var (x, y) = (pos.X, pos.Y);
    
    // clip 0% - 100%
    x = x < 0 ? 0 : (x > w ? w : x);
    y = y < 0 ? 0 : (y > h ? h : y);

    // convert to percentages
    var (x_perc, y_perc) = (x/w, y/h);

    // Do stuff with the two percentages
   
}

public void StartCapturing(object? sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs args){
    _isCapturing = true;
    CalculateCoords(args);
}

public void CaptureCoords(object? sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs args){
    if (!_isCapturing) return;
    CalculateCoords(args);
}

public void StopCapturing(object? sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs args){
    _isCapturing = false;
    CalculateCoords(args);
}
```

This methodology works fine while the cursor is inside the control. The problem comes when the cursor leaves the element: Movement tracking stops and, if click is released outside of the bounding box, the capturing will continue once the mouse re-enters the bounding box, even without click pressed.

These problems where to be expected. To eliminate them, the only possible solutions I have thought of but don't know how to implement them, are:

- Force-Capture Mouse events, even when pointer exits the control
- Restrain mouse movement within control's bounding box

Is there a way to do any of these two things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CapturePointer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.capturepointer?view=winrt-22621) in `StartCapturing`.

> You typically capture the pointer because you want the current pointer
> action to initiate a behavior in your app. **In this case you typically
> don't want other elements to handle any other events that come from
> that pointer's actions, until your behavior is either completed or is
> canceled by releasing the pointer capture**. If a pointer is captured,
> only the element that has capture gets the pointer's input events, and
> other elements don't fire events even if the pointer moves into their
> bounds. For example, consider a UI that has two adjacent elements.
> **Normally, if you moved the pointer from one element to the other,
> you'd first get PointerMoved events from the first element, and then
> from the second element. But if the first element has captured the
> pointer, then the first element continues to receive PointerMoved
> events even if the captured pointer leaves its bounds.** Also, the
> second element doesn't fire PointerEntered events for a captured
> pointer when the captured pointer enters it.

```
public void StartCapturing(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs args)
{
     _isCapturing = true;
     CalculateCoords(args);
     MainArea.CapturePointer(args.Pointer);
        
 }
```

Comment: I tried this method on `PointerExited`without success, so I'll also try it on `PointerPressed` and get back here to share the results. Additionally, is this method suitable even for out-of-window capturing?

Comment: This was indeed the correct way of doing it! I also confirm it works for out-of-window movement as well. Thank you!